# Storing and displaying data in Cordova app

Tags: php, ajax, database, cordova, web-applications

I'm creating this Cordova (Phonegap) app where I store users personal data (username and scores) every 60 seconds after which I want to display all users data to everybody (like scoreboard). For this I obviously need something to first gather all the data from users and then showing it to everybody.

I tried sending data with ajax to php for database storage. Then I tried sending data with ajax to php file to write the data in file, and finally realized that ajax won't work locally(?) (yes, I'm a novice). How do I create this kind of "global memory" that is accessible by all the users? How this is normally achieved in apps? I'm open for ideas.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You need a backend service, and call it from your application with webservices. You should send the data to your server (via webservice), store it in a database, and generate another call to send the scoreboard to every user.

Google about Rest APIS, choose the one you like.

For storing into the app, using localstorage is OK if the data is not too big. If it is, maybe you need to use SQLite, accesible from the cordova API.

Comment: Upvote and some [further info](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/offline/quota-research/) on limitations of the localstorage and databases on mobile devices.